# CSS: Image to have "Fixed" height, max-width, and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of pictures, each with different heights and widths that I want to put into a `div` tag. I want the picture to try to have a fixed height, unless the width exceeds a fixed amount, whereby I want the height to shrink to maintain the aspect ratio. I tried:

```
.ArtistPic
{
    height: 660px;
    max-width: 720px;
}
```

This fixes the height but if the image goes beyond 720px width, it squishes the picture horizontally and does not maintain the aspect ratio. Suggestions?

Edit: Maybe a better way of putting this is I'd like the picture to expand to one of those sizes and maintain the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Does this meet your needs?

```
.ArtistPic {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 660px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7s9wnjse/1/.

*Edit: Made answer simpler.*

Comment: Interesting image choice.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `background-size:cover;`

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/cukgh/3/

```
.box {
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:url("http://www.hdwallpapers3g.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Images-6.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you what you want:

## CSS

```
img {
    width: auto;  /* set to anything and aspect ratio is maintained - also corrects glitch in Internet Explorer */
    height: auto;  /* set to anything and aspect ratio is maintained */
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 0;  /* for older IE browsers that draw borders around images */
}
```

### [View here and re-size the window to see.](http://jsfiddle.net/AMR7J/)

Basically, just go get yourself a copy of **[Normalize.css](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/&ei=kYvYUs3YCZfNsQSD_oDADw&usg=AFQjCNFtErpRpsE81HuLMuGbnbC1_DIpdg&sig2=UiHa0S59yZw_5h_gNo4zOQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.cWc)**.

Answer (score 1):

If the height is fixed, it wont maintain aspect ratio, Set them both to be the max that you want, and it will maintain the ratio.

```
.ArtistPic {
  max-width: 720px;
  max-height:660px;
}
```

Edit:

Take a look at your image tags, they might have set width and height on them, If that is the case you will need to remove them.

```
<img src="image/path" width="250px" height="3005px" alt="valid image"/>
```

If it has width and height on it like that, you won't be able to fix with css.

Comment: I'd like the picture to expand to one of those two values and maintain the ratio. If the picture is smaller than either of those, it does not do that.

Comment: Check the edits, make sure your image tags dont have height and width attributes.

Comment: I made sure I wasn't. However, say the picture is 100px by 200px, I want the image to stretch to either the max width or max height. But not exceed either. With this, the image does not expand, it stays 100px by 200px.

Comment: You don't want to stretch the images bigger than they are. That is how it is supposed to be. Make the images bigger, so they can be *re-sized down* like you wish. This will also be better for retina devices, or higher resolution screens. While maintaining aspect ratio..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the element in a div with the fixed width/height:

```
<div style="width: 720px; height: 660px;">
  <img src="whatever" />
</div>
```